# visual studio says CMake binary deployment to the remote machine started. CMake generation will continue automatically after deployment finishes

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed the Windows subsystem for Linux(WSL) and Ubuntu 20.04 using Windows 10 store. Whenever I try to configure visual studio 2019 to compile and run a simple c++ CMake based project in the WSL, while I installed CMake in WSL, Visual studio says:

```
  The remote system does not have CMake 3.8 or greater. An infobar to automatically deploy CMake to the remote system will be displayed.
```

After clicking the yes button for the message shown in infobar, the visual studio says:

```
CMake binary deployment to the remote machine started. CMake generation will continue automatically after deployment finishes
```

And it takes forever. Nothing happens after it.

I use WSL-GCC-Debug configurationn.

Comment: Had this problem the other day. Make sure your WSL is connected to the internet and can install packages from the command line.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.It has, I installed CMake there.

Comment: I don't know then. If vscode fails to install cmake for some reason, there is no diagnostic of what really happens, or I don't know where to find it. So it's rather hard to fix. You should really check if WSL is connected right now, it is prone to lose its /etc/resolv.hosts from time to time.